# Avatar default is no longer working after adding AWS with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I had set up a default avatar when I set up Carrierwave.  It is no longer working.  I tried this work around in the view, but it isn't working either.  The default is always show, even after the avatar image gets uploaded by the user.

In my view:
    
        <% if @avatar.nil? %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(('/assets/images/default.png').to_s), user  %>
        <% else %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.to_s, collection: user), user  %>
        <% end %>

user.rb:
    validates_presence_of :avatar, allow_blank: true

I had also tried this as a workaround but didn't work:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    #@avatar = "/assets/images/'default.png'"
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to :back
    else
       flash[:error] = "Please fill in required information."
       render 'new'
    end
end
```

session_helper.rb

```
def avatar_changed?
    @avatar = Avatar.find(params[:id])
    if user && user.read_attribute(:avatar).present?
      user.read_attribute(:avatar)
    else
      user.avatar.recreate_versions!
      avatar.save!
    end
  end
```

Any suggestions on how I can set it up to have a default image but have it change if/when the user uploads one personally?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, how can you use both allow_blank and validates_presence_of? Don't you thing it's absolutely different staff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having a similar issue.  I was about to get this to work with the following in my view:

```
<% if current_user.avatar.present? %>
<%= link_to image_tag(current_user.avatar_url.to_s), current_user %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to image_tag(('/assets/images/default.png').to_s), current_user  %>
<% end %>
```

Depending on the view I changed the object between if user.avatar.present... and if @avatar.present? I had previously been trying to apply the instance variance (@avatar) universally which was not working.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a thread](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/882) in carrierwave repository. `default_url` just doesn't work when you use s3. They just didn't make it work.

And here is a possible solution:

1. move fallback images folder into app/assets/images
2. change default_url method like this, where ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] is the name of your s3 bucket

   ```
   def default_url
      image = [version_name, "default.jpg"].compact.join('_')
      "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}/assets/fallback/#{image}"
   end
   ```

I actually don't have solution for AccessDenied Error, but you can make this bucket public

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately this (or versions of it) didn't work for me either.